# Using Restangular with promises (deferred)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, restangular, deferred

In my app i'm using restangular, and i have such method (which i converted from the plain $http request).
And i don't know how to use correctly restangular with promises. How is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
var test = function(){
var data = '{"Office":"' + office + '"}';
var deferred = $q.defer();
var person = Restangular.one('persons', id)
$scope.person.patch(data).then(function (response) {
  deferred.resolve(response);
},function (err, status) {
  deferred.reject(status);
});
return deferred.promise;
}


var runIt = function(){
    test.then(...)...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use promise returned by `patch` method of `Restangular.one` instead of creating a new custom promise.

**Code**

```
var test = function() {
    var data = '{"Office":"' + office + '"}';
    var person = Restangular.one('persons', id);
    //returned promise
    return person.patch(data).then(function(response) {
        return response.data; 
    }, function(err, status) {
        return response.status;
    });
}

test().then(...)
```

Comment: but so i get angular.js:11706 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

check my updated code

Comment: @brabertaser1992 look at the updated, basically you should rename `$scope.person` to `person`, as person doesn't exist in $scope, it is javascript variable. see I did updated my answer, with how it will look in your code..

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Glad to help you. Thanks :-)

Comment: just one additional question: function(err, status) {
        return response.status; - what i should pass here, not response seems to me>

Comment: @brabertaser1992 as I can see your older code was passing error, so I did used `response.error`, if you would like to pass `result` then whole response object will get pass to caller function like `data`,`headers` & `status`